# Access another Inbox which is not mine Outlook Addin

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

How would I get a folder that I, as a user, have been added to.

I need to do an addin for work, how would I access an inbox which isn't *mine*?

[image]

So the top one is my personal inbox, I need to access the inbox within 'MIS'.

```
    Private Sub ThisApplication_NewMail() Handles Application.NewMail


    Dim myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim oParentFolder = myNameSpace.Folders("MIS")

    Dim mis = oParentFolder.Folders.Item("Inbox")
    Dim moveMail As Outlook.MailItem = Nothing

    Dim mItems As Outlook.Items = mis.Items
    mItems.Restrict("[Read] = true")
    Dim destFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = mis.Folders("Test")
    Dim SubjName = "TestingAddin123"
    Dim sender As String = "michael"
    Dim FName As String = "[Some recurring subject]"
    Dim tStamp As String = Format(DateTime.Now, "ddMMyy").ToString()


    Try
        For Each eMail As Object In mItems
            moveMail = TryCast(eMail, Outlook.MailItem)
            If Not moveMail Is Nothing Then
                If InStr(moveMail.SenderEmailAddress, sender) Then
                    If InStr(moveMail.Subject, SubjName) > 0 Then
                        Dim rn As New Random

                        Dim n = rn.Next(1, 9999)
                        'n()

                        moveMail.SaveAs("W:\NS\" & FName & "_" & tStamp & n.ToString() + ".html", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olHTML)

                        moveMail.Move(destFolder)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next eMail
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

So I'm using the above code so far but I don't seem to be able to find the MIS Inbox.
How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the Namespace.CreateRecipient / Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder methods.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I'll take a look on Monday. (First time developing Office Addins)